# How to import json file into AngularJs Application?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, import

I am using AngularJS and I have to import/export an array.

I could export the array object converting it into JSON object then using FileSave.js library to save the file locally.

Now I can't find any information about how to import this json file from my PC to my application, then converting it into an object to display the array.

Thanks

Comment: Did u tried $resource, $http????

Answer (score 4):

Client-side javscript is unable to access the local file system by design for security reasons. As far as I am aware, there are 4 possible solutions for you. I've listed them below in order of ease.

1) Create a variable in your program, and simply copy paste the contents of your json file into your js file as the value. This will take two seconds, but it can be really messy if your JSON file is large or if you need to use multiple json files.`var localJSONFile = [literally copy-pasted JSON text]`

2) Check out [Brackets by Adobe](http://brackets.io/). I just did some quick googling and found [this page](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Development-How-Tos) that shows how to access local files. Open that and do a ctrl+f > 'local' and you'll find it. This is my recommended approach, as it's fast and easy. You will have to switch your IDE, which if you are just starting out, then most IDEs (Brackets, Sublime, VSCode, Atom) will feel the same anyways.

3) Create a basic angular service to inject into your program with the sole purpose of storing copy-pasted JSON files as variables. This is ultimately the same as 1), but will help you make the files you are working in less cluttered and easier to manage. This is probably the best option if you don't want to switch IDEs and will have a couple JSON files you are working with.

4) Get a local server going. There are tons of different options. When I was in your position I went the [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) route. There is definitely a learning curve involved, as there is with learning to set up any server, but at least with node, you are still using javascript so you won't have to learn a new language. This is the recommended approach if you know you will need to have lots of different data files flowing back and forth between the project you are working on. If that is the case, you will ideally have a back-end developer joining you soon. If not, you can set up a server quickly by downloading node.js and npm (comes with it) and using npm from your command prompt to install something called express, and then express-generator. With express generator you can run an init command from your command line and it will build an entire fully functioning web server for you, including local folder structure, which you can instantiate with a quick command from your command prompt. Then you would just go to the file it provides for your routes and adjust it. Node.js CAN read your local file system, so you could set up a quick route that when hit, reads the file from your file system and sends it to the requester. That would let you move forward immediately. If you need to add a database later on, you will need to install a database locally, get the plugins from npm for that database (there are tons, so no worries there), and then update your route to read from the database instead.

Comment: this reminds me of the whole "make a mountain out of a molehill" thing

Comment: Really? Cuz when I first faced this problem a few months back, this is exactly what I found and was repeatedly told by more experienced developers.

Comment: I agree that you can't access the JSON file from a local set up - but "go learn Node" is a bit extreme for advice to a simple question, don't you think?

Comment: Though again, if there is an easier solution than the two I offered, I would also be really appreciative to learn about it!

Comment: Yeah, I usually don't assume people are developing data-centric applications without a local web server. Must be the more experienced developer in me.

Comment: sorry @Dude, I'm in a bad mood tonight. Your answer is correct, you just start in with setting up Node, then Express - now install Mongo, but you'll need a build system and maybe some continuous integration, but make sure you set up some unit testing and try a functional testing system, uh oh - now we want to virtualize it and contain it all - install vagrant and docker... etc, etc, etc.  If you'll make an edit to your answer, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: But then then we wouldn't be providing him any leads to take his work forward, just telling him that it's impossible to access that json file. I literally started teaching myself to code back in December, and I had to go through exactly that journey you described (at least parts of it... maybe I have yet to figure out that I'll need to do the rest you mentioned). It's can be pretty frustrating without sign posts along the way to help you out.

Comment: Actually - Just thought of another option :) Will edit and post now.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not here to discourage you or any other new developers. But the sea of tools available is vast, and you can lead people down really long paths. I don't think recommending Node is a bad idea, but there will be a learning curve for that - as there will be for any local web server. Maybe providing links to simple tutorials would help.

Comment: Now that's an answer! +1 and +1

Answer (score 0):

This seems too easy, so forgive me if I'm oversimplifying:

```
$http.get('/myJsonFile.json').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.myJsonData = data;
  });
```

Or, if your response headers aren't set up to serve `application/json`:

```
$http.get('/myJsonFile.json').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.myJsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  });
```

Comment: I think that doesn't solve my problem because I want to import the file from my PC and don't from a service.

Comment: So, you can copy/paste the json string into a js file that you include in your application. You just create a variable and set it to the json string:  `var myData = { "prop1": "val1", "prop2": "val2" };` -- be sure that there are no quotes surrounding the entire object.